# value not passing from child to parent component

Tags: lightning-web-components, child-to-parent, web-components

```
  @api label;
    uniqueId;
    @track placeholder;
   connectedCallback() {
    // Increment the static variable to get a unique ID
    unkDateInputId += 1;
    // Set the unique ID property using the incremented value
    this.uniqueId = `date-input-${unkDateInputId}`;
}   
   // Handle the date change and propagate the event to the parent component
    handleDateChange(event) 
    {
        const selectedDate = event.target.value;
            // Dispatch a custom event to notify the parent
            this.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('change', { detail: { value: selectedDate } }));
            this.value = new Date(selectedDate);

          this.formatDate();
    }

         formatDate() {
          if (this.value instanceof Date ) //&& !isNaN(this.value)) 
          {
              const day = this.value.getDate().toString().padStart(2, '0');
              const month = (this.value.getMonth() + 1).toString().padStart(2, '0');
              const year = this.value.getFullYear().toString().slice(-2); // Get the last two digits
              this.formattedDate = `${day}/${month}/${year}`;
              console.log('Selected date ',this.formattedDate);

          } else {
              // Handle invalid date
              this.formattedDate = '';  console.log('no date value');

          }
          // Dispatch a custom event to notify the parent
          this.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('change', { detail: { value: this.formattedDate } }));
      }
```

html

```
<label class="unkuk-label unkuk-date-input__label" for={date} if:true={label}>
                            {label}
                        </label>
                        <input
                            class="unkuk-input unkuk-date-input__input"
                            id={name}
                            name={uniqueId}
                            value={value}
                            placeholder="dd/mm/yy"
                            type="date"
                            onchange={handleDateChange}>
```

Trying to pass the label and Value to the parent is not working. Couldn't read date value in parent.

parent.html

```
    <div class="unkuk-date-input">
          <c-unk-date-input 
          data-form-element="enddate"
          name="enddate"
          label="End Date" 
          value ={model.enddate.value}
          required
          placeholder="dd/mm/yyyy"
          onchange={handleFormFieldChange}>
         </c-unk-date-input>
        
          </div>
```

parent.js

```
     @track model = {
        enddate:{value:undefined,error:undefined}
    
      };
        handleFormFieldChange(event) 
        {
          const field = event.detail?.fieldName;
    
          //if (!field) return;
      
          const value = event.detail?.value;
          const error = event.detail?.error;
          console.log('enddate' ,this.model.enddate);
          }
          
          handleFormFieldError(event)
        {
          this.handleFormFieldChange(event);
          console.log('handleFormFieldError triggered:', event.detail);
          //this.handleInvalidDate(event);
        }
```

Comment: Please share your parent cmp code also.

Comment: @TusharJadav Have added the parent cmp also.

Answer (score 2):

From what I can tell, sending the date and its label to the parent component already worked - almost. Here's a working solution based on the presented code:

Child component change handler:

```javascript
handleDateChange(event) {

    const selectedDate = event.target.value;
    
    if(!selectedDate) {
        this.value = undefined;
        this.formattedDate = undefined;
    } else {
        this.value = new Date(selectedDate);
        this.formattedDate = this.value.toLocaleDateString('fr', {
            year: '2-digit', 
            month: '2-digit', 
            day: '2-digit'
        });
    }

    this.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('change', { 
        detail: { 
            value: this.formattedDate,
            label: this.label
    }}));
}
```

Monitoring what happens in the parent component:

```javascript
handleFormFieldChange(event) {
    console.log('event.detail.value: ', event.detail.value, 
        ', event.detail.label: ', event.detail.label);
}
```

I'm in France, and we happen to use a date format similar to what is needed. I therefore used Javascript's toLocaleDateString with a "fr" setting.

Regarding the original code:

The code as it was fired two Custom Events: One with the entered String, the other with the date. I've replaced this with a single call.

I'm not sure why there was a console.log on `this.model.enddate` in the parent Javascript. `model.enddate.value` is passed to the child component, but only as a value; it won't change by whatever happens in the child component. Maybe that gave the impression it doesn't work?

(The code references a variable `unkDateInputId` in the child as if it is a local variable. I assume that the originally shown code is an excerpt. As it is, a declaration is missing.)

Generally, it has many benefits to use LWC's [lightning-input](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-input/example), of course. But you are probably aware of this.